# Batch file - Remote Copy and Execute issue

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, psexec

I have a batch file that part of it copies a folder and its content to a local directory and then continues through the batch process which then tries to execute the contents of the folder . locally run it works on all wintel os and copies the files from \networkshare\folder*.*  to %systemdrive%\temp\ .

I have attempted to use e.g psexec @serverlist.txt -c batfile.bat -s -f -d to copy the file and then execute it remotely how ever the issue is that this will not copy the files when run remotely . I think its a authentication issues after you a have remotely executed the batch file the remote system will not allow me to access/authenticate the networkshare

i have tried xcopy , copy , robocopy .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can only authenticate against the next hop using implicit credentials. Connection attempts from the first hop to a second hop will fail, even if your user has the required permisssions. See e.g. [here](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230) for an explanation.

Try this:

```
psexec @serverlist.txt -u %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% -d -c batfile.bat
```

Use explicit credentials so you're authenticated against the remote host. With that the second hop will be the next hop for your authenticated session. Don't run the script as LOCAL SYSTEM (`-s`), because that account is restricted to local resources.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past.  Instead of trying to copy/run  the BAT file just run the script things from a UNC path if you are able to.  I think the problem lies in the BAT file not actually able to run through PSEXEC and copy like you think.  Does it give an exit code?

Here's an example I used a while ago to install Adobe reader.  I tried to do it through a batch file but no dice.  I could not get it to run within the batch file whether I copied it or not.  I can't remember the exact reason, I think it had something with the way a batch file is called in the system and runs in some sort of local context.  Don't quote me on that though as I can't remember the exact why.

Here is my code example:

```
psexec /accepteula \\%computer% -s cmd /c msiexec /i "\\UNC\Software\adobe\Adobe Reader 7.0.9.msi" TRANSFORMS="acrobat7.mst" /qn
```